# Could I use a microcontroller to put a HDD or SSD into my RAM slots

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, microcontroller

Could I use a microcontroller to put a SATA storage device into a RAM slot, or would some BIOS configuration prevent this.

I know that this is beyond useless, but it may be a fun project.

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: Not gonna work, speeds are way too low. Would crash the system.

Comment: The complicated and high speed interface used by the DRAM slot would make this a very complex project that would be well beyond anything outside of some very high speed FPGAs or high power controllers. Then the latency of HDDs would make for some very weird and slow "RAM".

Answer (score 2):

1. The system won't *recognize* the device as a SATA device. It's a RAM slot that's wired specifically to the memory controller, it's not a generic PCIe slot – all it can handle is RAM (or something that pretends to be exactly like RAM).

   It's the same reason why you can't connect a SATA disk to the VGA port, or to the PS/2 keyboard port, or even the USB port, and have it somehow show up as a SATA device.

   <sup>(although those *may* be possible to some extent due to VGA ports having I2C, but this would still require not just a custom microcontroller but custom drivers on the PC side as well)</sup>
2. A generic programmable microcontroller probably won't be fast enough to handle DDR4.

   I've just recently read about someone creating their own RAM for an 8088 in this way – a 44-year-old CPU – and it was just barely fast enough. (I hope I'm not mixing up two different projects though.)
3. Having a SATA device that pretends to be RAM is going to absolutely tank performance. You can already achieve this by setting up a swapfile (pagefile) on the SSD in your OS, and there's a reason it's only used to offload less-used pages that don't fit in RAM; even new NVMe SSDs are still much slower than RAM. (More expensive SSDs literally use internal DRAM caches to work faster.)

There do exist commercial [NVDIMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVDIMM) products that provide persistent storage through a DRAM interface – and they have special handling from both the system and the OS – but they're mostly found only on enterprise servers.